# Camera2 PNG capture

Tags: android, png, android-camera2, camera2

I am working on a camera application using the Camera2 API. I am able to capture a RAW (.dng file) and jpg. I saw that it is possible to take a PNG photo on the Camera FV-5 Application and I would like to do the same. I am able to get the ByteBuffer of the RAW and each pixel's individual RGB value (if this helps...). PNG capture is important as I want to make this feature possible so I have something in between RAW and JPEG (RAW's is too large, JPEG compresses too much. PNG is a lossless compression format.). Thanks!

Comment: Please try to include a _question_ in your question. Where is your problem? What have you tried so far? Can you add some source code?

Comment: Camera apps that allow to save PNG are currently doing a simple trick, they convert programmatically the JPEG obtained from the capture into a PNG, nothing more than that. And so, to convert the image to PNG you will need to decode the JPEG into a bitmap and then save it as PNG. Not the most elegant way to offer the option PNG to users, but this the current existing mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the bitmap, which it sounds like you do, then you can save it as a PNG:

```js
OutputStream imageStream = new FileOutputStream("yourImage.png");
yourImageBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, imageStream);
imageStream.close();
```